# Accessing Angular2 routes from browser, nginx server

Tags: javascript, php, angular, nginx, routes

Here is the problem,

Concrete example is "confirmation email" for registration.

I did a register component in my angular2 application. Which works pretty fine, it sends a confirmation email with a url like this :

```
https://www.host.com/application/rootFolder/confirmEmail?token=1238344139041
```

GET Token value is supposed to identify the user/email, and confirm validity in the "confirmEmail" component of the application.

But, and somehow logical, it fails when browser tries to call this URL directly since it does NOT really exist on server!

On server, for this app, only

```
https://www.host.com/application/rootFolder
```

exists! subfolders do not exist, the "sub-routes" are managed by angular2 router...

The server I use is

```
nginx 1.10.1
```

There is no specific "location" config in default.conf file, only the "fastcgi_pass" for php files.

So question is :

How to get the server redirect the request to the app_root directory, but keeping the childroute parameters... ?

How, once redirected on root dir, to manage the url parameters (/confirmEmail?token=1238344139041) to make angular2 router get to the right component with GET parameters?

Thanks for reading/help